# Is there a word for lying on the bed peacefully, all your muscles relaxed?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there a word or an idiom for lying on the bed peacefully and happy? Throwing yourself down on bed arms wide open, all your muscles relaxed and staring at the ceiling with a happy smile like something you dreamed of has just happened. Is there an idiom to narrow this situation?

Comment: [Shavasana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavasana) - although it's not really an English word :-)

Comment: @Lucky: Great word. But it's Sanskrit. I doubt even people here in India would use it that way. Have no idea how many people in US know this word from Yoga.

Comment: @Lucky: Also, arms aren't wide open in this asana. Just saying.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I agree (both about the arms and not being an English word) that's why I put it in a comment and not an answer. It's just that words happy+peaceful+lying+relaxed reminded me of the asana :-). But I could have mislead the OP by accident, thanks for preventing that ;-)

Comment: @Lucky: We have a `too broad` reason for closing. I'm thinking we should have a `too narrow` reason too.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Yup. I think neologisms are a big no-no here, otherwise one could combine your and Dan Bron's answer into: The person plunged in a *serene-spread-eagleish-state*. But then English would start to look like German :-D

Comment: @Lucky :D Reminds me of Rose from '2½ Men': I've been riddled with "glaukenschtuken" ever since./  Glauken? - Schtuken./
It means: " Feeling guilty for having felt schadenfreude"./
"They've got a word for that?"/ "Not yet. But I'm hoping "glaukenschtuken" catches on".

Answer (score 13):

There are a few terms which specifically capture the physical state of lying on the ground, face up, but they're fairly clinical and lack the mental overtones you describe (of complete relaxation, etc).

Nevertheless:

> ***Supine***: (of a person) *lying face upward.*
> <sub>[google definition]</sub>

Which I like because its spelling reminds me of "supple" (relaxed, like a loose, floppy noodle). And there's also:

> ***Recumbent***: (especially of a person or human figure) *lying down.*
> <sub>[google definition]</sub>

Which I like because it has hints of "recline" and "slumber".

Now, there are a couple of other words which are often used to mean ***lying on one's back***, but in a strict technical sense, they actually mean ***lying face down***:

> ***Prostrate***:  *lying stretched out on the ground with one's face downward* 
> <sub>[google definition]</sub>

As a verb, *prostrate*¹ often carries an *active* connotation of laying face down in reverence or submission.

A more passive synonym, often used of the unconscious (e.g. boxers who have been knocked out) and corpses is:

> ***Prone***: *lying flat, especially face downward.* 
> <sub>[google definition]</sub>

This is the difference: [image: comparison of supine and prone]
<sub>image credit: paramedicine.com</sub>

You'll notice that none of these words explicitly describe one's arms and legs being outstretched.  Now, if you *truly* need to capture that physical arrangement, you can use:

> ***spread-eagle***: *stretched out with one's arms and legs extended.*
>
> "prisoners are chained to their beds, spread-eagle, for days at a time"
> <sub>[google definition]</sub>

But I *strongly* recommend you [avoid that term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadeagle_(position)%23Sex_position).

If the actual physical arrangement of your body is less important than the mental state of relaxation you're trying to convey, then you can use my personal favorite word from this particular constellation²:

> ***repose***:
>
> 1. *a state of rest, sleep, or **tranquility**.*
>
>      "in repose her face looked relaxed"
> 2. *a state of resting after exertion or strain*
> 3. *peace, tranquillity* 
>      
>    <sub>[Merriam-Webster definition]</sub>
>    <sub>[google definition]</sub>

But again, that lacks the explicit physical state of laying flat on the floor.

So, if you need to capture both the physical and mental states, you can say something like "*I was **relaxing on the floor***", or "*I was just **floating there***" (metaphorically invoking the image of floating on water), or, heck, "*I was so relaxed, I just **gave myself up to gravity***".

<sub>¹ Don't confuse *prostrate* and *prostate* (with only one `r`), please.

² Why do I like this particular word? Because I once read a wonderful short story about a living car, and one line the admiring narrator used to describe it was something like "*That car didn't **park**, it **reposed**.". Sadly, that's all I can remember of the story; its title is lost to me forever.</sub>

Comment: Upvote. I want to give you another upvote for the warning about prostate!

Comment: @MystiSinha Not sure that's the kind of paper trail you want to leave on the internet.  If you ever run for office, that quote could be taken waaaaay out of context ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [tranquil](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/tranquil)

> quiet and peaceful

or its synonym, [serene](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serene)

> Calm, peaceful, and untroubled

Or better yet,

**[reposeful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repose#repose__19)**

> (in) a state of rest, sleep, or tranquility:

Though I must admit, neither of these are applied exclusively to describe lying on bed.

[Oxford]

Comment: tranquil, reposeful, calm, placid, serene... none of these adjectives include arms wide open and staring at the ceiling with a happy smile on one's face.

Comment: @Centaurus: I said that already. Question is, what does?

Comment: To me this is just like "What is the single word for seeing your neighbor in town and not being able to talk to him?"

Comment: @Centaurus: Someone asked that? Seriously?

Answer (score 2):

How about something based on the intransitive verb "loll?"

"Sit, lie, or stand in a lazy, relaxed way: 'the two girls lolled in their chairs'" --O.E.D.

"Scene four begins early the next morning with an indolent Stella, sexually satisfied and smug, lolling in bed." --[Bloom's Guides: Tennessee Williams's *A Streetcar Named Desire*, p. 40]

Answer (score 0):

in a simile, could you use...?

**[Snow angel](http://www.libertyk12.org/News/2010-11/110810_snowangel.cfm)**